# Twilio programmable voice, how to know from which platform the call was accepted

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-voice

Consider the following code

```
 Device.on('incoming', call => call.accept());
```

How do I add info fields like "platform" to know from which the call was answered.
I have electron application, web application and native application all doing the same, I need to know from which device the call was accepted.

**update**
I did think about a solution which is to register the devices across all the platforms with different ids instead of the same one to represent the platform, and then make sure we dial to 3 `<client>` instead of one.Is this is the way to go with it?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't add any extra metadata to the call object itself.

Your idea to set up your clients with different identities and then fan out the calls to them with multiple [`<Client>` elements](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client) inside the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) would certainly work.

Alternatively, I would suggest you store the metadata about the call in your own database.

Comment: But how do you suggest doing it, Now all the 3 platforms have the same identity so on incoming call all 3 rings, I don't see a way to store this data unless the call will be answered by different identities based on the platform.

Comment: Is your application aware of the platform it is running on?

Comment: yes they are...

Comment: So your application can record that it answered the call and which platform it was on in your own database.

Comment: I though about the idea to make a request to the backend once that call is answered from the platform but this will have problems with native platforms because of restrictions when the application is closed when answering the call, ill go with different client identities

Comment: Cool, either way is good!